# How do I reference native ASP controls in Typescript?

Tags: asp.net, typescript

I downloaded JQuery and other d.ts libraries but I cannot find anything at all about references to native ASP controls. It seems they should just be there as part of the ecosystem. I have no trouble referencing JQuery or Devexpress controls. Is there some magic line I am missing in the tsconfig.json file? Example:

```
constructor(pnl: UpdatePanel) {

}
```

gives me the error: "cannot find UpdatePanel".

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "obj",
    "bin"
  ],
  "include": [
    "Scripts/typings/*",
    "Scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I added the '"types": [],' line after reading about issues with conflicting downloads. But I have had no automatic downloads of any kind and removing that made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way ASP controls will "just be there" in a JavaScript ecosystem. You can search for types [here](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/). If you can't find the ASP controls you're looking for, they don't exist, but you can create them by writing your own `.d.ts` files.

Comment: I'm not talking about my own user controls. I am talking those supplied by Microsoft as part of the ASP envioronment. For example, UpdatePanel, HIddenField, etc. Typescript is not recognizing those. I am certain that I am missing something in the configuration, just can't find what that is.

Comment: I know what you're talking about, but it sounds like you're under the assumption that because Microsoft created TypeScript and also created ASP that they somehow know about each other and that's absolutely not the case. There's no tsconfig setting that enables ASP anything. TypeScript has zero knowledge of ASP. The only way to provide such knowledge is to install types and that requires `npm install --save-dev @types/something-asp`. And it looks like it doesn't exist. So write your own or don't.

Comment: I thought it was quite a reasonable assumption given that I have seen nobody else asking this question. So, seriously, everybody BUT Microsoft jumped onboard with library definitions? There HAS to be a .d.ts file out there somewhere already. It's not like Typescript is new. I am just new to it because I am a server guy who has inherited a massive web application.

Comment: Marked this as the answer since, incredulous though I may be, I can find nothing to contradict this answer. It does, in fact, appear that nobody cares about type definitions for standard ASP controls. Perhaps that's because there are so many full-featured JS libraries out there that the standard controls aren't often used in newer projects.

I suppose it is also worth pointing out that most of those controls don't have a client-side interface anyway. You'd have to create your own mirror of the C# interfaces built around the associated DOM elements.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's a huge market for providing ASP types to TypeScript. Very rare that anyone should need this. It's 2019! Sorry you've inherited such an old project!

Comment: To be totally fair, I ran this project from the beginning and authorized the approach that was taken --- starting in 2006. I had just expected it to be completely replaced by newer tech by now. As a server guy, I focused my efforts on a strong server architecture and left the UI to guys who had some experience with ASP. Shortly after, I lost the most experienced guy to a startup. Then a few years ago my team started the next gen cloud. I stayed behind to prepare for maintenance mode by upgrading the libraries, not rewriting it. The upgrades broke some stuff so here I am.